# Indexing created JLabels into 2D Jlabel array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel

I have 36 already created `JLabel` components in Swing, with 6 x 6 size manner. I named them like this

```
Subject1Semester1
Subject1Semester2
Subject1Semester3
...
Subject6Semester5
Subject6Semester6
```

And I have created a corresponding label array:

```
JLabel[][] score = new JLabel[6][6];
```

How to index every single label into the array so I could do a looping method to set text the labels easier?

Comment: Get rid of then `Subject1Semester` labels and instead simply use the `score` array.  Assign the labels directly to the array - `score[x][y] = new JLabel("...");`

Comment: I suggest reading a tutorial on arrays in Java, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Don't tag the IDE. It is irrelevant to a question about coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent any other information (assuming this array should be **constant**), I would not use loops. Instead, I would replace `JLabel[][] score = new JLabel[6][6];` with

```
JLabel[][] score = { { Subject1Semester1, Subject2Semester1, Subject3Semester1,
        Subject4Semester1, Subject5Semester1, Subject6Semester1 },
        { Subject1Semester2, Subject2Semester2, Subject3Semester2,
                Subject4Semester2, Subject5Semester2, Subject6Semester2 },
        { Subject1Semester3, Subject2Semester3, Subject3Semester3,
                Subject4Semester3, Subject5Semester3, Subject6Semester3 },
        { Subject1Semester4, Subject2Semester4, Subject3Semester4,
                Subject4Semester4, Subject5Semester4, Subject6Semester4 },
        { Subject1Semester5, Subject2Semester5, Subject3Semester5,
                Subject4Semester5, Subject5Semester5, Subject6Semester5 },
        { Subject1Semester6, Subject2Semester6, Subject3Semester6,
                Subject4Semester6, Subject5Semester6, Subject6Semester6 } };
```

Comment: So the JLabels can't be renamed by `.setText`?

Comment: @RaviEdhoNugraha Sure they can, I assumed they were already correctly labeled and setup and you wanted an easy way to create the array. how did you create your 36 jlabels and arrange them in your 6x6 grid? I can only answer based on the information you have provided.

Comment: That is not your code.

Comment: I think i've done it myself. Thanks for the help!